# New to installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I have Windows 10 on my SSD 102/240 Gb available and a 2Tb HDD. Both of the SSD and HDD are MBR, if i convert them to GPT would work?
I used rufus to set up the pendrive. I also made a partition on the HDD.  Should I install it on the SSD instead of the HDD?

Then when I rebooted to install the option to force UEFI pop out , but choose to go back and quit.

On my system information my BIOS mode is UEFI, on the partition I made is MRB. 
How shoud I proceed? My motherboard is a b350 tomahawk with the latest BIOS update.

Also Cmdlet not supported on this platform too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select to install it in `UEFI` mode your ubuntu installer will automatically partition your hard drive, unless you click on manual partitioning option.

Comment: I just converted the ssd to gtp and switch the bios Legacy+uefi to uefi so far so good, now should i try again but on the ssd ? sorry for my bad english

Comment: Yes you should try to install it on ssd, it should work just fine.